# Rails - Check if Parent model attribute is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-attributes

I want to display a list of teachers who have had their accounts connected to our payment purchaser provider. When a teacher connects their payment account it updates a payment uid field on the User model.

Our models are set up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :teacher

class Teacher
    belongs_to :user
```

My Teachers Controller:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @teachers = Teacher.order('created_at DESC')
    end
```

I want to display something like this:

```
@teachers = Teacher.where(self.user.uid.present?).order('created_at DESC')
```

But I am returned a NoMethodError 'undefined method `user' for TeachersController'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@teachers = Teacher.joins(:user).where.not('users.uid = ?',nil).order(created_at: :desc)
```

**OR**

```
valid_users = User.where.not(uid: nil).pluck(:id) # return array of all user's id which has not uid nil
@teachers = Teacher.where(user_id: valid_users).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Well on this one there's no error but none of the teachers display.

Comment: @donaldduck : have you check the data in DB is there any relevant data to satisfied this condition? check by removing `.not` and let me know still you can't see any result?

Comment: @donaldduck : I have updated my answer with another option and it must work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope method:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.connected
    includes(:user).where.not(users: { uid: nil }).references(:user)
  end
  ...

end
```

You'll use this like:

```
@teacher = Teacher.connected.order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: that returns an error: "SQLException: no such column: user.uid"

Comment: Try plural users: { uid: nil }. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: @donaldduck : try removing `u` from `uid` and just write `users: { id: nil }`. see if it works.

Comment: @BrentEicher Now I"m getting a `undefined method 'class_name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I'm happy to move this into a chat and help you debug your program.

Comment: Thanks Brent but I've gotten it resolved. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting teachers that have a user?

```
@teachers = Teacher.where.not(user_id: nil).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing but uid is an attribute on the user model and I only want to display those teachers whose parent user has the uid not be nil.